# Convert Image hyperlink into <img> with PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I have this block of code that has a URL to an image. How can convert that into  tag with the src? here is the sample code

```
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item odd"><a type="image/jpeg; length=72486" href="http://www.xyz-website.com/files/263780_147936011949340_128540677222207_316406_533387_n.jpg">263780_147936011949340_128540677222207_316406_533387_n.jpg</a></div></div>
```

So from the above code, I want to convert that into something like this

```
<div><img src="http://www.xyz-website.com/files/263780_147936011949340_128540677222207_316406_533387_n.jpg"/><div>
```

I also want to do this for a particular domain. in the example above its xyz-website.com

Thank you.

Comment: How are you getting this HTML? scraping from a site? Generating it yourself?

Comment: @Marc B: Those are definitely FB's images.

Comment: no its not FB's images. I am writing an RSS reader and certain sites put their intro images in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need. You will want to modify it to be more specific to your needs. But this uses a regular expression to help extract the image path and saves all found images to an array that you can then use to output it.

```
$str = '<div class="field-items"><div class="field-item odd"><a type="image/jpeg; length=72486" href="http://www.xyz-website.com/files/263780_147936011949340_128540677222207_316406_533387_n.jpg">263780_147936011949340_128540677222207_316406_533387_n.jpg</a></div></div>';

preg_match('/href="(.)+"/', $str, $matches);
$image_extensions = array('.jpg', '.bmp', '.png');

foreach ($matches AS $match)
  foreach ($image_extensions AS $ext)
    if (stristr($match, $ext . '"')) //I add the double-quote to the string to signify the end of the href param and prevent string detection confusion
      $images[] = str_replace(array('href="', '"'), '', $match);

foreach ($images AS $image)
  echo "<div><img src='$image'/><div>";
```

Comment: This will not work because I have to replace that <a> tag with the img tag

Comment: Did you even try the code out??? I tried it on my local system and it does just that. This code will literally get the url from the <a> tag and extract just that. Then you can wrap it with whatever you want. This means that this code will literally do everything you asked for unless you need to clarify what you are looking for. Please try the code out first before you write it off.

Comment: I will add that it uses the image extensions array to detect known image types and so it excludes results that are not accepted images.

Answer (score -1):

use regex.

```
preg_replace('~<div class="field-item odd"><a type="image/jpeg; length=72486" href="(.+?)">(?:.+?)</a></div></div>~i', '<div><img src="$1"/><div>', $str);
```

something like this

Comment: Can you make it more generic instead of this hard coded exact <div and class etc? Basically I need to look for an <a> tag that can have href at any location in the tag and I can specify a particular domain to it

Answer (score -1):

You could explode the a tag and grab the info you want:

```
$all_html = '263780_147936011949340_128540677222207_316406_533387_n.jpg';
$tmp1 = explode('href="', $all_html);
$tmp2 = explode('"', $tmp1[1]);
$image_url = $tmp2[0];
if (strpos($image_url, 'xyz-website.com') > -1) {
    //only output image if the url of the image includes 'xyz-website.com'
    echo '';
}
```

Comment: Why use these splits instead of just regex?